# Find the sum of this series: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ $\dfrac{n}{2^{n-1}}$

Tags: summation

May I know how I should go about finding the sum of this series?

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ $\dfrac{n}{2^{n-1}}$

I am really stuck. Thanks!

Comment: Multiply the series in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910021) by $4$ and subtract the first term (which is $0$).

Comment: Do you know differentiation? (If not, there are still other ways.)

Comment: Yeah I do. I'm just not sure, should I estimate the value of the series using integration...? Or am I supposed to do like some manual calculation of partial sums..?

Comment: Here is one way, using differentiation. You should be able to sum: $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n}}{2^{n-1}}$ (hint: it's twice a geometric series). Once you have that, differentiate with respect to $x$ - that will give you a formula for: $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{nx^{n-1}}{2^{n-1}}$ (do you see why?) Once you have that, set $x=1$, and you have your desired result.

Comment: To supplement the comment of columbus8myhw, you can have a look at the following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qk3cza4GmRQ

Comment: Another way is to let $\displaystyle S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$. See if you can get $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n-1}{2^{n-1}}$ in terms of $S$ in two different ways.

Comment: Is the first summation equals to -$\frac{x}{1-x}$? Does differentiating with respect to x give -$\frac {1}{(1-x)^2}$? Or did I get that wrong?

Comment: This is a [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Comment: Right I got it, thanks for the comments and the video link! Was really useful. :)

Comment: a similar approach used to answer the question asked here recently would be applicable.
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910021/computing-sum-i-0-infty-fraci2i1/910120#910120

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Consider the expression $$A=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n x^{n-1}$$ You recognize that $A$ is just the derivative with respect to $x$ of $$B=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n}$$ which is a geometric progression. So, $$B=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{n}=\frac{x}{1-x}$$ and its derivative with respect to $x$ is then $$A=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$$ Now, replace $x$ by $\frac{1}{2}$.

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 3):

$$s=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{n}{2^{n-1}}=1+2/2+3/2^2+4/2^3+5/2^4+....(1)$$
By dividing whole equation by $2,$
$$\dfrac{s}{2}=\dfrac{1}{2}(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{n}{2^{n}})=1/2+2/2^2+3/2^3+4/2^4+5/2^5+....(2)$$
Now$(1)-(2)$ gives us,
$$\dfrac{s}{2}=1+1/2+1/2^2+1/2^3+1/2^4+....=1+1$$
Hence we can obtain $s=4.$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way without differentiation.

Let
$$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^{n-1}}=\frac{1}{1}+\frac{2}{2}+\frac{3}{4}+\frac{4}{8}+\dotsb$$
Now, let's see if we can get $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n-1}{2^{n-1}}$ in terms of $S$ in two different ways.

First way:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n-1}{2^{n-1}}&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{2^{n-1}}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \\
&=S-\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\dotsb\right) \\
&=S-\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=S-2
\end{align}

Second way:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n-1}{2^{n-1}}&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n-1}{2^{n-2}} \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(0+\frac{1}{1}+\frac{2}{2}+\frac{3}{4}+\frac{4}{8}+\dotsb\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}S
\end{align}

Since these must be equal, we have:
$$S-2=\frac{1}{2}S$$
Solving, we get $S=4$, which is the answer.

Comment: Interesting method!

Comment: @inggumnator Thank you! However, now that I see Nilan's answer, I must say: my argument is really just a convoluted version of Nilan's.